# Error while creating web service using Apache Axis 2

Tags: web-services

From an example i am using the web service (SOAP) AXIS-WS, But at run time i am getting "The Apache Axis2 Web service runtime in Tomcat v7.0 Server does not support the service project " err. Please let me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My WEB Dynamic Module version is 3.0 and can be bring down.

Comment: add some code to get idea whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[image]**If you are getting above error while trying to create web service using Apache Axis2 it means your project has been created on higher version of dynamic web project. Apache Axis2 does not support dynamic web project above 2.5 version. Please change to lower version 2.5**.

**To change**: **Right click project** –> **Properties** –> **Project Facets** –> **Dynamic web module and change to version 2. 5**. (If you are not able to change to version 2.5 please create new eclipse project with Dynamic web module 2.5)

***Hope it Helped***